# How to move around multiple slides in prezi?

Tags: prezi

I have setup a presentation with prezi.com and would like to change the order of slides. Alas, I only seem to be able to move around one slide, or fame, at a time. This makes the process of regrouping the path rather tiresome, as I want to restructure the current slide by presenting the topic in different order, and each topic has about 10 to 15 slides.

Is there a way to group slides and move them at once?